# Azure Synapse - Import python scripts in notebooks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

Am using Azure Synapse in combination with jupyter notebooks:
[image]

Many of my jupyter notebooks import some custom python scripts like the util-import: [image]

However, there's no option hold *.py files in Azure Synapse. Always when i use the import functionalty, the *.py is transformed to a notebook (On laptop it was util.py, after Synapse import it's a notebook):

[image]

How can custom *.py files be used in Azure Synapse Notebooks, without transforming them from *.py to notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for adding python to Synapse. You can manage them at the [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-workspace-packages), [pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-pool-packages), or [session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-session-packages) level. The method I've had the most success with is loading from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) to a Spark Pool, but you can also upload Wheel or JAR files to your workspace and reference those in your notebooks. One caveat on using PyPi is that if the package has a dependency on C library packages, Synapse won't load it into your pool.

Comment: While I appreciate the response, I'd like to add a note of caution: Importing a local Python file stored alongside the notebooks for seamless code sharing isn't straightforward. While the methods you mentioned (workspace, pool, session, and PyPi) can be used, they often introduce significant overhead. This can be especially challenging when working with a utility file that's still under development and hasn't reached maturity or stability.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the workspace imports generally require full packages, which doesn't seem to be what this question is asking for.

You can effectively import single files in R or python with .R and .py files respectively by reading the file from the associated abfss and then evaluating it with the corresponding python or R functions that can evaluate strings as code.

In R or python you can run

```
file_string = mssparkutils.fs.head("abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/Path/to/file.<R or py>")
```

This will create a string variable containing the entire contents of the file. Then, in python, you can run

```
exec(file_string)
```

Or in R you would run

```
eval(parse(text = file_string))
```